# Apache authentication using 'AuthDigestProvider file dbd' order seems to be wrong

Tags: mysql, apache, authentication

I am testing the migration of apache authentication from using file to using dbd and mysql.  I am using apache 2.4.6 on a CentOS 7 server.  At present I want to keep both file and dbd authentication working until I am happy that it is working correctly.
Here are the relevant bits of my configuration:

```
LogLevel debug
#
ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ "/var/www/dummy/cgi-bin/"

# mod_dbd configuration
DBDriver mysql
DBDParams "dbname=myDb user=somebody pass=somepassword"
DBDMin      4
DBDKeep     8
DBDMax      20
DBDExptime  300

<Directory "/var/www/dummy/html">
    Options Includes FollowSymLinks
    # Only needed if we use .htaccess for authentication
    AllowOverride None

    AuthType Digest
    AuthName "Realm"
    AuthDigestDomain /var/www/dummy/
    # nb use dbd first and if that fails use file 
    # Well this keeps on failing 1-Sep-2014
    # AuthDigestProvider dbd file
    # Whereas this succeeds (huh??) with 
    # the error.log indicating (at LogLevel debug)
    # it is due to dbd-group being granted
    AuthDigestProvider file dbd

    # These are specific to dbd
    AuthDBDUserPWQuery "select pass from blah where UserName=%s"
    AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "select Realm from blah where UserName=%s)"
    # The first column value of each row returned by the query statement
    # should be a string containing a group name.
    # Zero, one, or more rows may be returned.
    AuthzDBDQuery "select GroupName from blah where UserName=%s"

    # These are specific to file
    AuthUserFile /somewhere/passwd
    AuthGroupFile /somewhere/group

    # We require either dbd-group or failing that file group
    <RequireAny>
        Require dbd-group mygroup
        Require group mygroup
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

According to apache documentation (http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/auth.html):

```
AuthBasicProvider file ldap
Require valid-user
```

In this example the file provider will attempt to authenticate the user first. If it is unable to authenticate the user, the LDAP provider will be called."

The RequireAny directive is not necessary as there is an implied OR between successive Require statements but I have included it to make it explicit.

Now if I make the order in the AuthDigestProvider directive "AuthDigestProvider dbd file" it fails in both Require dbd-group and Require group.  However if I make the directive "AuthDigestProvider file dbd" it succeeds and the log file indicates:

**[authz_core:debug] [pid 22474] mod_authz_core.c(802): [client ...] AH01626: authorization result of Require dbd-group mygroup: granted.**

My question is: does this indicate that apache has granted access using dbd, or has it really granted access using file and it is pretending that it used dbd??

The followup question is: If this succeeds with 'file dbd' order, why does it fail with 'dbd file' order - surely if either succeeds it should succeed no matter what order is used?

NB Please do not respond about the choice of digest vs basic authentication this is simply a test.

Comment: _“does this indicate that apache has granted access using dbd, or has it really granted access using file and it is pretending that it used dbd?”_ – shouldn’t you be able to find that out by using two different users, one in file and one in dbd, and authenticate once which each … and then see what the log says?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion CBroe. I added a user in the database that was not in the file and authentication failed.  I did read in 'https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/FAQ#How_do_I_set_up_Apache_to_require_a_username_and_password_to_access_certain_documents.3F' something about modules that dont authenticate by default.  The advice was "Just add the appropriate 'XXXAuthoritative yes' line to the configuration", but I am not sure that this applies to 2.4 and I have not found an appropriate directive anyway...

Answer (score 0):

Well I have done a little more experimentation with this and I now suspect that digest authentication is broken in authn_dbd on 64-bit machines.  I have checked the response hash received from client browsers that get returned to the server and they match rfc-2617, but both apache-2.4.6 (apr-1.5.1, apr_util-1.5.3) and apache-2.2.27 (apr-1.4.8, apr-util-1.5.2) running on different 64-bit machines return "password mismatch: /" error and as they should be constructing the comparison hash on the same input values then obviously they are not getting the result as defined in rfc-2617.

I dont get any mysql errors, so I assume this is returning the right values (strings that were generated by htdigest) and it does when I test the queries directly on the database.  I have configured the mysql database to return ascii character values for the username, realm and password field, so it should not be a character encoding issue.  As the passwords match OK when using 'file', I can only assume that authn_dbd calculates a different hash to that returned by authn_file???

Actually there was an error in my configuration that I did not pick up at the time.  The AuthDBDUserRealmQuery actually returns the password not the realm (see mod_authn_dbd documentation), so it should be:

AuthDBDUserRealmQuery "select pass from Users where UserName=%s and Realm=%s"

and the AuthDBDUserPWQuery should be removed